# DevExpress WPF Grid export to excel - additional rows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I have a DevExpress WPF grid (version 9.3). When I export to excel, it has horrible additional rows* that completely mess up excel's functionality such as auto filter.

[image]

I've been trying to make sense of the documentation and I think that the solution may lie in setting **TableView.PrintCellStyle** somehow. But it's really not clear.

I am using the **TableView.ExportToXls(string path);** method.

**Is there a quick way of switching off this behaviour and getting a working xls file?**

*I understand that this is to help with creating a spreadsheet that looks the same as the grid. Horrible default behaviour - a working spreadsheet is more important than it looking like the UI.

**EDIT**: @DmitryG - I have tried this and now, instead of three lines I now get two. Better, but not solved.

[image]

I have also checked the [KB article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q298262.aspx) you cited and get the following result:

[image]

I am using version 9.3.6.

**Anything else I can try?**

**EDIT 2:** Have tried the value converter approach. Getting the same additional row.

[image]

Worst case, is there anyway of excluding these columns from the export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was still getting the additional rows. The quickest and easiest way to get around this was to set the EditSettings of the column so it exports 'True' or 'False', export the grid then set the column back to a checkbox.

Thusly:

```
public void ExportGridToExcel()
{
    TableView.Grid.Columns["*FieldName*"].EditSettings = new TextEditSettings();

    TableView.ExportToXls(@"C:\temp\spreadsheet.xls");

    TableView.Grid.Columns["*FieldName*"].EditSettings = new CheckEditSettings();
}
```

NB It's the **fieldname** the column is bound to and **NOT the column name**. That caught me out for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the problem like yours was already discussed here:
 [Exporting Boolean Values causes Three Merged Rows To Appear for each Row of data](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q298262.aspx).
The problem solution for version 9.3 was the direct assigning of the GridColumn.EditSettings property:

```
<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="Boolean" FieldName="Boolean">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:CheckEditSettings HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Please also review the following KB article:
[How to change representation of data cells via PrintCellStyle when printing/exporting grid data](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18513.aspx).

P.S. This problem is absent in the latest versions.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this and it has reduced the two additional rows from two to one. Anything else I can try? I have updated the question with my results.

Comment: You can also try to replace the standard CheckBox printing appearance with a meaningful text representation. Please place the TextEdit within a cell's display template and bind its Text property to the cell's value via a converter that will return an appropriate text... (this approach is demonstrated in the KB article).

Comment: Tried that. Get the same result. Anything else I can try? Or can I exclude the columns from the export? That would be better than nothing.

Comment: Can you please post your grid-columns markup? Because it is not quite clear to me from your screenshots.
BTW, the best solution for you it is a creation of issue in the[DevExpress Support Center](http://help.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraGaugesCoreModelLinearScale_Valuetopic.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress has [significantly improved](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/thinking/archive/2014/11/11/winforms-asp-net-and-wpf-grid-controls-new-excel-data-export-engine-coming-soon-in-v14-2.aspx) the export engine in the latest version 14.2 and now the issue should be solved.
 
Please refer to the following help article for more information:

[Printing and Exporting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6160)